# How can I authenticate with OAuth2 when running a script?

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, reddit

I'm having the same problem with [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) and with the [reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/). Both of these APIs require authentication using OAuth2.

Since I'm only running a script I do not have any "redirect uri". What can I do to still use OAuth2 with my script?

Answer (score 0):

To kind of answer my own question, after further investigation I found [this python example](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example#python-example) on reddit. I should check if this type of request works for the MS Graph API as well since doint it in postman is cumbersome.